# Append div when user scrolls 100px from bottom of page

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I'm using angularjs and trying to append a footer to the html element of my page.  When the user scrolls to within 100px of the bottom of the page I want the footer to disappear and when the user has scrolled up from the bottom more than 100px I want the footer to appear.  My css fixes the footer to the bottom of the page.  I've got it working for the header.

This is the closest I've got so far, but its not quite right.  This should be easy but clearly I'm missing something, any ideas?

```
controller: ['$scope', '$window', function($scope, $window) {
    var hasHeader=false;
    var hasFooter=false;
    var myEl = angular.element(document).find('body');
    angular.element($window).bind("scroll", function() {

     $scope.$apply(function() {
        $scope.header;
        $scope.footer;
     });

    if($scope.header == true) {
         if (this.pageYOffset >= 100 && hasHeader == false) {
              myEl.prepend('<div id="header">Header content here</div>'); 
              hasHeader=true;
         } else if(this.pageYOffset < 100 && hasHeader == true) {
              var header = angular.element('#header');
              header.remove();
              hasHeader=false;
         }
      }

      console.log('$window.screen.height: ' + $window.screen.height + ' | this.pageYOffset' + this.pageYOffset)

      if ($scope.footer == true) {
         if(this.pageYOffset >= 100 && hasFooter == false) {
               myEl.append('<div id="footer">Footer content here</div>'); 
               hasFooter=true;
         } else if((this.pageYOffset >= ($window.screen.height - 100)) && hasFooter == true) {
              var footer = angular.element('#footer');
              footer.remove();
              hasFooter=false;
         }
      }

      $scope.$apply();
    });
}],
```

[This](http://hoteldemo.freevar.com/angular-header-footer/) is what I've got so far.  It should do the same as the header.

Comment: *"its not quite right"* isn't much of  a problem description. Please understand that we can't see this, or know what expectations of *"right"* are

Comment: Also...what is `myEl` and where is it defined. If it's inside a directive `ng-class` would solve your problem

Comment: I've added some more detail, hope that makes it more clear.

Comment: None of that code belongs in controller. Controller should never do dom manipulation...use directives for that. Is also more complicated than it needs to be when these would be really simple directives

Comment: doing dom manipulation is new to me and I wanted to at least get it working before trying to improve it.

Comment: ok...that's cool. Good time to learn about directives. Let angular manage the dom for you. That's what it's for. Also note will be easier to maintain the html for header and footer as templates not as string in the javascript

Comment: I agree with that entirely, at the moment this is more a learning exercise than anything else.

Comment: FYI - the reason controller isn't good for the dom is because it will fire before any templates associated to that view will even exist. In your simple case it will work but in more robust routing it won't

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think you have to use a directive for that. and put an `ng-show` on the footer element, and when the scroll distance happens, show the element..

i'll try to write a sample directive for you now

```
.directive('scrollDirctv', ['$document', '$window', function($document, $window) {
    return {
        scope: {
            scroll: '=?scrollDirctv',
            method: '&scrollMethod'
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            var windowEl = angular.element($window);
            var offset = 0;
            var handler = function(e) {
            var docHeight = ($document.height !== undefined) ? $document.height : $document.body.offsetHeight;
            var windowHeight =  $window.innerHeight;
                offset = $window.pageYOffset - (docHeight - windowHeight);
                if(attrs.scrollMethod != undefined){
                    if(offset>100){
                        scope.method();
                    }
                }
            }
            windowEl.on('scroll', scope.$apply.bind(scope, handler));
            handler();
        }
    };
}])
```

and put the directive on the element, and assign a function to it,

(`<div scroll-dirctv scroll-method="myFunction()" >`) so that you can change the toggle used for `ng-show` inside the function...

Comment: So I would just add a function called `method()` to my controller and that would enable me to set a value for toggling the showing of the footer?

Comment: inside the controller you have to define the function that you're using in html. and in my example, that would be `myFunction()`. because that's the function you're passing to the directive with the `scroll-method="myFunction()"` attribute. so in the controller define it like this: `$scope.myFunction = function(){...}` . and inside that, you can change the toggle as you said...

Comment: i just edited the code because there were some typos in it... check it again

Comment: Nice one thank you.  I'll study it and see if I can implement my intentions :)

Answer (score 1):

You should not do DOM manipulation from the controller. Instead, you should create a directive and update some properties there, so that you can show and hide the header and the footer using `ng-show` and let Angular do the DOM manipulation for you.

Your directive should look something like this:

```js
app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.directive("scroll", ["$document", function ($document) {

  function getDocHeight() {
    return Math.max(
      document.body.scrollHeight, document.documentElement.scrollHeight,
      document.body.offsetHeight, document.documentElement.offsetHeight,
      document.body.clientHeight, document.documentElement.clientHeight
    );
  }

  function scrollController($scope, $window) {
    var vm = this;

    vm.isHeaderVisible = false;
    vm.isFooterVisible = true;

    function checkScroll() {
      var scrollY = this.pageYOffset;
      var maxScroll = getDocHeight() - $window.innerHeight;

      console.log('scrollY = ' + scrollY + ', maxScroll = ' + maxScroll);

      // HEADER:

      if (vm.hasHeader) {
        if (scrollY >= 100 && vm.isHeaderVisible === false) {
          console.log("Show header");
          vm.isHeaderVisible = true;
        } else if(scrollY < 100 && vm.isHeaderVisible === true) {
          console.log("Hide header");
          vm.isHeaderVisible = false;
        }
      }

      // FOOTER:

      if (vm.hasFooter) {
        if(scrollY < (maxScroll - 100) && vm.isFooterVisible === false) {
          console.log("Show footer");
          vm.isFooterVisible = true;
        } else if(scrollY >= (maxScroll - 100) && vm.isFooterVisible === true) {
          console.log("Hide footer");
          vm.isFooterVisible = false;
        }
      }

      $scope.$apply();
    }

    angular.element($window).bind("scroll", checkScroll);
  };


  return {
    controller: ['$scope', '$window', scrollController],
    bindToController: {
      hasHeader: '@',
      hasFooter: '@'
    },
    controllerAs: 'scroll',
    scope: true
  }
}]);
```

```css
#page {
    position: relative;
    height: 1000px;
}

header,
footer {
    position: fixed;
    height: 50px;
    line-height: 50px;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
}

header {
    background: red;
    top: 0;
}

footer {
    background: blue;
    bottom: 0;
}

.as-console-wrapper {
  background: #e9e9e9;
  top: 60px !important;
  bottom: 60px !important;
  max-height: none !important;
  left: 10px !important;
  right: 10px !important;
  border: none !important;
  border-radius: 2px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 8px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .125);
}
```

```html
<div data-ng-app="myApp" id="page" data-scroll data-has-header="true" data-has-footer="true">
    <header data-ng-show="scroll.isHeaderVisible">HEADER</header>
    <footer data-ng-show="scroll.isFooterVisible">FOOTER</footer>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.8/angular.js"></script>
```

Note I also changed some of your logic that I think is not right.